# Complement of a Vitali set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

We know that it holds for the Vitali set that $V\subset [0,1]$ and that Vitali set is unmeasurable. I know that the complement $\mathbb{R}\setminus V$ is also not measurable. However, I was wondering if we can say that $[0,1]\setminus V$ is also not measurable?

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra of (Lebesgue) measurable sets is closed under complements and countable unions and intersections.  If $[0,1]\setminus V$ is measurable, then $$(-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty) \cup \left[ [0,1] \setminus V \right] $$ is measurable.  Hence...

Answer (score 2):

If $U = [0, 1] \setminus V$ is measurable, then so is $U^c$ and in turn, $[0, 1] \cap U^c = [0, 1] \setminus U = V.$
Therefore, $U$ cannot be measurable.

In general, if $B$ is a measurable set and $A \subset B$, then $A$ is measurable iff $B \setminus A$ is.